# "Correct" definition of localisation of modules using universal property

Tags: abstract-algebra, localization

Let $A$ be a ring and $S\subset A$ be a multiplicatively closed system and $M$ an $A$-module. I have seen the following universal property of the localisation of $M$ at $S$:

$S^{-1}M$ is an $A$-module map $M \rightarrow S^{-1}M$ which is an initial object in the following category:

- the objects of the category are $A$-module maps $M \rightarrow N$,
  where $N$ is also an $S^{-1}A$-module with the $A$-module structure
  given by multiplying with $a/1$;
- the morphisms between two objects $\phi_1: M \rightarrow N_1$ and $\phi_2: M \rightarrow N_2$ are module maps $\alpha: N_1 \rightarrow N_2$ satisfying $\alpha \circ \phi_1 = \phi_2$.

My question is, in this definition, do we suppose $\alpha$ to be $A$-module maps, or do we put the stronger condition that $\alpha$ are $S^{-1}A$-module maps.

While it seems natural to put the stronger condition on the $\alpha$'s, is there any concrete reason to put the stronger condition other than the fact that... we can (in the sense that the well-known concrete construction for localization does guarantee an $S^{-1}A$-module map between $S^{-1}M$ and any $S^{-1}A$ module $N$)?

Comment: They're equivalent.

Comment: Why are they equivalent?

Comment: Check it for yourself! More precisely, the claim is that if $\alpha : N_1 \to N_2$ is an $A$-module homomorphism between two $S^{-1} A$-modules then it is automatically already an $S^{-1} A$-module homomorphism.

Comment: Ah, does this follow from the fact that an $S^{-1}A$-module is the same as an $A$-module where all the maps $s \times \cdot: N \rightarrow N$ are isomorphisms?

Comment: Well, yes, it does, but you should check how.

Comment: I think it goes like this. $A \rightarrow S^{-1}A$ is initial in ring maps $A \rightarrow B$ where $S$ is sent to invertibles. Now we have such maps $A \rightarrow End(N_1)$ and $A \rightarrow End(N_2)$. Also $A \rightarrow End(N_1) \rightarrow Hom(N_1, N_2)$ commutes with $A \rightarrow End(N_2) \rightarrow Hom(N_1, N_2)$ where the last arrows in both chains are given by $\alpha$. Therefore $S^{-1}A \rightarrow End(N_1) \rightarrow Hom(N_1, N_2)$ also commutes with $S^{-1}A \rightarrow End(N_2) \rightarrow Hom(N_1, N_2)$, and this just means $\alpha$ is an $S^{-1}A$-module morphism. Is it ok?